# Find the middle term in the expansion of $\left(x^2 - \frac{7}{x^3}\right)^{18}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the middle term in the expansion of
       $\displaystyle \bigg (x^2-\frac{7}{x^3}\bigg)^{18}$.

$k=4 ,  n=18$

$=\sum^{18}_{k=0}$$ (^{18}_k).(x^2)^{18-k}.(\frac{7}{x^{3}})^{k}$
   $=(^{18}_4).(x^2)^{14}.(\frac{7}{x^{3}})^{4}$

it is correct answer?

Comment: Why do you choose $k=4$? There are $19$ terms, so presumably the tenth term is the "middle" one.

Comment: To add to what rogerl said, note that we start counting at $k = 0$.

Comment: True not be aware of the number of good

Comment: Correct way or not?

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  Read rogerl's comment.

Comment: @rogerl i have 18 terms why put 19 terms ?

Comment: You start counting at $k = 0$ and end with $k = 18$, which is $19$ terms.

Comment: and K=(18/2)-1 = 8 ? this i think "middle "one

Comment: You should have $k = \frac{18}{2} \color{red}{+} 1$ to account for the $k = 0$ term.

Comment: $$\left( \begin{matrix}
   18  \\
   9  \\
\end{matrix} \right){{({{x}^{2}})}^{18-9}}{{\left( \frac{-7}{{{x}^{3}}} \right)}^{9}}$$

Comment: $\displaystyle \bigg (x^2-\frac{7}{x^3}\bigg)^{18}$.
$k=8 ,  n=18$
$=\sum^{18}_{k=0}$$ (^{18}_k).(x^2)^{18-k}.(\frac{-7}{x^{3}})^{k}$
$=(^{18}_8).(x^2)^{10}.(\frac{-7}{x^{3}})^{8}$

Comment: because i start k=0

Comment: It is good: you have $7347060\cdot x^{16}$

Answer (score 1):

By the Binomial Theorem, 
$$\left(x^2 - \frac{7}{x^3}\right)^{18} = \sum_{k = 0}^{18} \binom{18}{k}(x^2)^{18 - k}\left(-\frac{7}{x^3}\right)^k$$
Since the index $k$ ranges from $0$ to $18$, there are $19$ terms in the expansion.  The middle term is the tenth of these $19$ terms.  Since we begin our count at $k = 0$, the tenth term is $k = 9$.  Hence, the middle term is 
$$\binom{18}{9}(x^2)^9\left(-\frac{7}{x^3}\right)^9 = -\frac{1961992372340}{x^9}$$